# QT program on Ubuntu

Tags: c++, qt, ubuntu

I made a qt program on Windows XP and it runs great. Now when I try to run that program on Ubuntu 10.10 , it gives me error "Not Supported". I have included all the required QT libraries and .dll files required to make the program portable are present in the folder of the program but its of no use.. I am using QT 4.7.

Thanks

Comment: Uhh.. DLL files? You recompiled the program right?

Comment: NO i didn't recompile the program.I think, There is no need to recompile, cuz I am using program.exe in Debug folder.

Comment: There definitely is a need to recompile. Your Windows executable (and all the DLLs that it uses) isn't going to work on Linux.

Comment: @Hassan I think he wants to run the program using wine, which is unnecessary, of course. But I think it should work, too?

Comment: It should, but this would be a very strange way of asking for help with wine.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You will have to recompile it with QT Creator under linux. Take care of 32 and 64 bit if it should be portable. QT is generally cross plattform but your windows executables are not.